# ¿Cómo realizar una ventana que muestre los valores de una lista?

Tags: java, lista, interfaz-gráfica, jframe

El problema es el siguiente:
Tengo una lista simplemente enlazada de nodos con 4 campos de información y quiero hacer una opción en que despliegue una ventana en netbeans (Jframe), que muestre todos los nodos de la lista. Es decir que cuando presione siguiente muestre la siguiente información del nodo sucesor.

El código que he hecho es el siguiente:

El problema de este fragmento de código es que cuando presiono la opción muestra todos los nodos bien pero cuando abro y cierro la ventana solo me muestra el ultimo nodo y me arroja el mensaje que no hay más nodos en la lista.

```
package proyecto3;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class p9 extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
private macroDep auxiliar = new macroDep ();
//La clase proyecto 3 es donde esta los atributos departamentos modo públicos y static
public p9 () 
{
    initComponents();
    auxiliar = proyecto3.departamentos;
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    if (proyecto3.empleados.empty() == true) 
    {
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "No hay empleados que mostrar");
       dispose ();
    }
    else
    {
        code.setText(proyecto3.departamentos.first.getCode());
        datesign.setText(proyecto3.departamentos.first.getFecha());
        ced.setText(proyecto3.departamentos.first.getCedem());
        name.setText(proyecto3.departamentos.first.getName());
    } 
}   

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (auxiliar.first.getNext() == null) 
    {
       JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "No hay mas empleados que mostrar");
       dispose (); 
    }
    else
    {

        code.setText(auxiliar.first.getCode());
        datesign.setText(auxiliar.first.getFecha());
        ced.setText(auxiliar.first.getCedem());
        name.setText(auxiliar.first.getName());
    }
    auxiliar.first = auxiliar.first.getNext();
}
```

Lo que busco obviamente es que muestre los nodos correctamente y que cuando se cierra y abra empiece del primero  hasta mostrar el ultimo.

Cualquier respuesta recomendación es de gran ayuda. Agradezco el tiempo que toman escribiendo sus respuestas.

Nota: En el programa no uso librerías que manejen listas, manejo las que hice.

Comment: Consejo corto es usar `JList` con `JListModel` y un `ListCellRenderer`. Si no se encuentra nadie para apoyarte con esta pista, te respondo cuando encuentro tiempo.

Comment: Me ayudarías muchisimo.

Comment: Disculpa, mi primera impresión fue que tu problema era con presentación en una lista, pero revisando me parece es más un tema de falta de recursión. Luego lo voy a estudiar de nuevo. Tu tratas de mostrar partes de un arbol binario desde un nodo, cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto una implementación completa de una lista `JList` usando un `ListModel` y un `ListCellRenderer`. Tu puedes construir una `JList` así con cualquier tipo de objeto que mantienes en una lista `List<ClaseObjeto>`, usando el una vista que te conviene. Para agregar mas funcionalidad, puedes:

- agregar listeners a la vista de los items
- agregar métodos al modelo para cambiar el contenido, como `get`, `remove` etc.
- si cambios en el modelo no se te muestran, simplemente puedes llamar a `validate()` a la `JList`.

  ```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Component;
  import java.awt.EventQueue;
  import java.awt.Font;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
  import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JList;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
  import javax.swing.ListModel;
  import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

  public class ListaEjemplo extends JFrame {
      private JList contentPane;
      private Modelo modelo;

      /**
       * Launch the application.
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  try {
                      ListaEjemplo frame = new ListaEjemplo();
                      frame.setVisible(true);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          });
      }

      /**
       *  Constructor que crea la lista con modelo y renderer y lo coloca como contenido
       */
      public ListaEjemplo() {
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
          modelo = new Modelo(generarItems());
          contentPane = new JList(modelo);
          contentPane.setCellRenderer(new Renderer());
          setContentPane(contentPane);
          contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      }

      class Modelo extends AbstractListModel implements ListModel{

          private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

          public Modelo(List<Item> items){
              this.items.addAll(items);
          }

          // necesario para que la lista mide el tamaño necesario
          @Override
          public int getSize() {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return items.size();
          }

          // necesario para que la lista puede obtener los elementos del modelo
          @Override
          public Object getElementAt(int index) { 
              return items.get(index);
          }
      }

      // el renderer de celulas construye una vista para el objeto cada vez que la lista lo necesita
      class Renderer implements ListCellRenderer<Item>{

          // necesario
          @Override
          public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
              JList<? extends Item> list, Item value, int index,
              boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

              // creamos la vista para nuestro objeto

              JPanel view = new JPanel();
              view.setLayout(new BoxLayout(view, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

              JLabel titulo = new JLabel(value.titulo);
              titulo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
              view.add(titulo);

              JLabel contenido = new JLabel(value.contenido);
              contenido.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.ITALIC, 10));
              view.add(contenido);            

              return view;
          }

      }

      // representación de los objetos que se muestran en la lista
      public static class Item {

          public final String titulo;
          public final String contenido;

          public Item(String titulo, String contenido){
          this.titulo=titulo;
          this.contenido=contenido;
          }
      }

      // método para generar datos de prueba
      private static List<Item> generarItems(){
          ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
          for (int i = 1; i<=5;i++){
              list.add(new Item("Item "+i,"Lorem ipsum factum andate a la punta del cerro"));
          }
          return list;
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo, me has dado varias ideas y eso era lo que buscaba, bien amigo :D.